How to optimize for rotation and translation in 3D for the next equation?
Let us consider we have two known $SE3$ transformations with matrix representations $H_1$ and $H_2$ of the form $H= [R; t]$ where $R$ is a 3x3 rotation matrix and $t$ a 3x1 translation vector. I am omiting the row of zeros below $R$ and the 1 below $t$. Also consider the next relationship is true:
$H_2 = A^{-1}H_1A$
where $A$ is itself an $SE3$ transformation. What could be a good try to find $A$? Notice we can have many instances of $H_2$ and $H_1$ so in principle I would also be interested in posing this question as an estimation problem.
Thank you!

what is the purely rotational version and can you solve it?

The rotational version would be $R_2=R^T_AR_1R_A$
, I tried to pose it as a least squares problem but I do not know how to take it from there. Any ideas?

suppose $R_1$ Is unity and $R_2$ isnt. Then there is no solution. I think this is the rule, and not the exception

If I would know $R_1$ and $R_A$ I would be able to compute $R_2$. My question is how to recover $R_A$ back from $R_1$ and $R_2$ only

i gave you a counter example where no such $R_A$ exists
